# Google BigQuery Visit data per date

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to retrieve sum of visits who have an custom dimension hit within their visit split date.
I get this data with the help of this query as sum for all selected dates, but how do I get it split by date?

Many thanks in advance!

```
select sum(sessions) as total_sessions, from (
  select
    fullvisitorid,
    count(distinct visitid) as sessions,
    from (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-09-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-09-03')))
    where totals.visits = 1
AND hits.customDimensions.index = 3 
AND hits.customDimensions.value = 'play'
    group each by fullvisitorid
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ga_sessions tables have `date` field (see [Analytics to BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719))

So, if you want to stay with BigQuery Legacy SQL for your above query - you can use this `date` field, as in below example

```
SELECT date, SUM(sessions) AS total_sessions FROM (
  SELECT
    date, 
    fullvisitorid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT visitid) AS sessions
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-09-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-09-03')))
  WHERE totals.visits = 1
  AND hits.customDimensions.index = 3 
  AND hits.customDimensions.value = 'play'
  GROUP BY date, fullvisitorid
)
GROUP BY date
```

If you can/want [Migrate from BigQuery Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql) to [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) you can use below example:

```
SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS date,
  COUNTIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimensions)
                  WHERE TRUE OR (index = 3 AND value = 'play'))) AS sessions
FROM `XXX.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE totals.visits = 1
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-03'
GROUP BY date
```

See more details about using [Wildcard Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this with your table using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options")? I may have misunderstood the question, but it computes the total number of visits for each day matching the condition on `customDimensions`, which I believe is what you want.

```
SELECT
  _PARTITIONTIME,
  COUNTIF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimensions)
                  WHERE index = 3 AND value = 'play')) as sessions
FROM `XXX.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE totals.visits = 1
GROUP BY _PARTITIONTIME;
```